# Showing $Ha=H$ if and only if $a$ belongs to $H$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let be $H$ a subgroup. Show $Ha=H$ if and only if $a$ belongs to $H$.

Here what I have understand of the proof: $a$ must belong to $Ha$ because $ea=a$ where $e$ is the identity in $H$. So the only way $H=Ha$ is that a belongs to $H$.

Is that correct?
Now suppose that a belongs to H. for every element h in H, $h=(ha^{-1})a$. This implies that h belongs to Ha so also a belongs to Ha. This implies H=Ha.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

If $a\in H$, then every element of $H$ can be written in the form $(ha^{-1})a\in Ha$ and due to closure, $Ha=H$. Contrarily, if $Ha=H$ then $a=ea\in Ha=H$.

Comment: $ha^{-1}$ always belongs to H because by definition of group, the composition of two elements of a group h and a belongs always to the same group H right?

Comment: Correct, in general for a group $(G,\circ)$ and elements $x,y\in G$, $x\circ y\in G$ to satisfy the closure axiom. Furthermore, $x^{-1}$ exists to satisfy the inverse axiom.

Comment: ok thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in G$. Then

\begin{align}
Ha=H &\iff Ha=He \\
&\iff ae^{-1}\in H \\
&\iff a\in H.
\end{align}

This is due to the more general theorem that [$Hx=Hy$ if and only if $xy^{-1}\in H$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2123476/104041).